# Print with Presets Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have two types of documents I need to print, both with preset print options selected.
One preset is named "Cover", printing from tray 1 in a heavy gsm.
The other is named "Doc", printing from tray 3 is recycled paper.
Neither is the default preset.

After running through a basic record macro, they both come back with:

```
Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, Item:= _
        wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, Copies:=1, Pages:="", PageType:= _
        wdPrintAllPages, Collate:=True, Background:=True, PrintToFile:=False, _
        PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, _
        PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0
```

I want to be able to click the button in the Quick Access toolbar, and it'll print that preset for that document.

Answer (score 0):

The printer tray can be set on the Paper tab of the Page Setup dialog.

You can find an example of setting the tray in a macro in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158858/word-macro-for-other-tray-printing).